# Why doesnt this code generate the random code?

Tags: java, random, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Generator{
//9352141NTBG1223

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> int2Array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int six = 0;
    int seven = 0;
    int N_one = 0;
    int N_two = 0;
    int N_three = 0;
    int N_four = 0;
    Character Middle1 = 'A';
    Character Middle2 = 'A';
    Character Middle3 = 'A';
    Character Middle4 = 'A';

    Random gen1 = new Random();

    charArray.add(Middle1);
    charArray.add(Middle2);
    charArray.add(Middle3);
    charArray.add(Middle4);
    intArray.add(one);
    intArray.add(two);
    intArray.add(three);
    intArray.add(four);
    intArray.add(five);
    intArray.add(six);
    intArray.add(seven);
    int2Array.add(N_one);
    int2Array.add(N_two);
    int2Array.add(N_three);
    int2Array.add(N_four);

    for(int i: intArray) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    i = k;
    }
    for(int i: int2Array) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    i = k;
    }
    for(char i: charArray) {
        int b = gen1.nextInt(20);
        switch (b) {
        case 1: i = 'H'; break;
        case 2: i = 'R'; break;
        case 3: i = 'F'; break;
        case 4: i = 'Y'; break;
        case 5: i = 'U'; break;
        case 6: i = 'Q'; break;
        case 7: i = 'T'; break;
        case 8: i = 'N'; break;
        case 9: i = 'B'; break;
        case 10: i = 'L'; break;
        case 11: i = 'K'; break;
        case 12: i = 'P'; break;
        case 13: i = 'I'; break;
        case 14: i = 'Z'; break;
        case 15: i = 'X'; break;
        case 16: i = 'V'; break;
        case 17: i = 'C'; break;
        case 18: i = 'E'; break;
        case 19: i = 'M'; break;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Generated Code: ");
    for(int i: intArray) {
    System.out.print(i);
    }
    for(char i: charArray) {
    System.out.print(i);
    }
    for(int i: int2Array) {
    System.out.print(i);
    }
}

  }
```

Im a pretty experienced programmer so i designed a code this code used to be in methods and stuff but it just would not work so i tried it straight forward in the main method and it does not generate me a random code it just prints out the defaults! What is going on i have tried everything! This makes no sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i: intArray) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    i = k;
}
```

thats not how you add a value to a list, you're just assigning `k` to the local variable `i`. try:

```
for(int i=0; i<intArray.size(); i++) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    intArray.set(i,k);
}
```

you should make similar adjustments to the other parts of your code where you commit the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In (for example) `for(int i: intArray)`, `i` isn't an *alias* for the elements of `intArray`; it's just a variable that's set to each element of `intArray`. So this:

```
    for(int i: intArray) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    i = k;
    }
```

is equivalent to this:

```
    for(int index = 0; index < intArray.size(); ++index)
    {
        int i = intArray[index];
        int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
        i = k;
    }
```

(i.e., it sets `i` equal to `intArray[index]`, but then sets it to something completely different). What you really need is this:

```
    for(int index = 0; index < intArray.size(); ++index)
        intArray[index] = gen1.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: intArray isn't actually an array, it's an ArrayList so intArray[index] wont work.

Comment: @yurib: Quite right, thanks. I initially wrote as though it were an array, then I realized it was a list, and made only half the necessary changes. But, no matter. The OP is "a pretty experienced programmer", so I'm sure (s)he'd have no difficulty with that sort of detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loops you're not assigning the value into the lists, so their values are not changed.

```
for(int i: intArray) {
    int k = gen1.nextInt(10);
    intArray.set(i, k);
}
```

is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your int loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int2Array.size(); i++) {
  int2Array.set(i, gen1.nextInt(10));
}
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.size(); i++) {
  intArray.set(i, gen1.nextInt(10));
}
```